# remove div from inside embedded object with jQuery

Tags: jquery, object, select, tags

I am embedding an object onto my site and want to remove a div from it. Is that possible?
I want to remove a div with a certain id inside object tags with jQuery. I tried the jQuery below but that does not select div's inside the embedded object.

```
$("div").filter(function(){
console.log(this.id); // i don't see any of the id's from the div's inside my object 
});
```

EDIT:

```
<object data=http://www.msn.com width='100%' height='100%'>
<embed src=http://www.msn.com width='100%' height='100%'>
</embed> Error: Embedded data could not be displayed. </object>
```

I need to remove a div inside the embedded object on my site.

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Use `this.id` instead. You are creating a jQuery object which doesn't have `id` property.

Comment: Use either `this.id` or `$(this).attr('id')`

Comment: @undefined instead of $(this).id?

Comment: I still not not see div's inside the object

Comment: @undefined I can still only see div's on my site, not the stuff that I am getting with object. I want to remove a div that I am getting from another site

Comment: `filter` doesn't remove the elements, you should use `remove` method instead.

Comment: @milan works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/6Leph/

Comment: @undefined the problem is i cannot select div's inside the tag object. i know how to remove.

Comment: @wirey yes but that does not answer my question

Comment: Can you provide a demo on http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: @milan Where's your question?  You want to remove what element?

Comment: Hmm.. so you are embedding a page into your page.. and want to remove a div from there?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(this).attr('id')  // $(this)  is jQuery Object
```

**OR**

```
this.id //  this is DOM Object
```

/

```
$("div").filter(function(){
       return this.id != 'div1' && this.id != 'div2' ;
}).css('backgroundColor' , 'orange')​
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/AYCw2/1/)**

Comment: Please re-read my question, I did an edit to clarify better. thanks

Comment: though $(this).prop('id') is probably more consistent with this.id since id is a property the element - Notice the property `.` notation

Comment: @wirey ..Thanks for pointing that out... I feel id is not a property of an element , rather an attribute.... If you are telling me in-terms of attr() vs .prop() , I don't think it should be a problem for static attributes..